# Submit button affecting more than the one row it is supposed to

Tags: php, mysql, forms

So I've gotten this all working but for some reason the buttons in each column keep affecting all the rows in that column. So for instance if I have 3 records in the database and I click the button in CallAttemptOne (Row 3) it'll affect rows 1,2,3. What am I doing wrong here? Thanks

(Also yes, I realize the code is deprecated. That's step two!)

```
//superfluous code removed

$table = 'Project_Submissions';

if (!mysql_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pwd))
    die("Can't connect to database");
if (!mysql_select_db($database))
    die("Can't select database");

//Display all fields
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM {$table} ORDER BY ID DESC");

//superfluous code removed


while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
{
    echo "<tr>
    <td style='font-size:12px;'><center>{$row['ID']}</center></td>
    <td style='font-size:12px;'>{$row['First_Name']} {$row['Last_Name']}</td>
    <td style='font-size:12px;'><center>";

    //-------------------------------------------------
    if(empty($row['CallAttemptOne']))
    {
    echo" 
        <form action='".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."' method='post'>
        <input type='hidden' id='ID' name='ID' value='{$row['ID']}' />
        <input type='submit' name='formCalledOne' id='formCalledOne' value='Called' />
        </form>
        {$row['CallAttemptOne']}";
    }
    else
    {
    echo "{$row['CallAttemptOne']}";
    }


    echo "</center></td><td style='font-size:12px;'><center>";

    //-------------------------------------------------
    if(empty($row['CallAttemptTwo']))
    {
    echo" 
        <form action='".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."' method='post'>
        <input type='hidden' id='ID' name='ID' value='{$row['ID']}' />
        <input type='submit' name='formCalledTwo' id='formCalledTwo' value='Called' />
        </form>
        {$row['CallAttemptTwo']}";
    }
    else
    {
    echo "{$row['CallAttemptTwo']}";
    }


    echo "</center></td><td style='font-size:12px;'><center>";

    //-------------------------------------------------
    if(empty($row['CallAttemptThree']))
    {
    echo" 
        <form action='".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."' method='post'>
        <input type='hidden' id='ID' name='ID' value='{$row['ID']}' />
        <input type='submit' name='formCalledThree' id='formCalledThree' value='Called' />
        </form>
        {$row['CallAttemptThree']}";
    }
    else
    {
    echo "{$row['CallAttemptThree']}";
    }


    echo "</center></td><td style='font-size:12px;'><center>";

    //-------------------------------------------------
    if(empty($row['EmailAttempt']))
    {
    echo" 
        <form action='".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."' method='post'>
        <input type='hidden' id='ID' name='ID' value='{$row['ID']}' />
        <input type='submit' name='formEmailAttempt' id='formEmailAttempt' value='Emailed' />
        </form>
        {$row['EmailAttempt']}";
    }
    else
    {
    echo "{$row['EmailAttempt']}";
    }


    echo "</center></td>

    //-------------------------------------------------
    <td style='font-size:12px;'><center>Text Area</center></td>
    <td style='font-size:12px;'><center>{$row['Received_Date']}</center></td>
    <td style='font-size:12px;'><center>

        <form action='".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."' method='post'>
        <input type='hidden' id='ID' name='ID' value='{$row['ID']}' />
        <input type='submit' name='formDelete' id='formDelete' value='Delete' />
        </form>


    </center></td>
    </tr>";

}
    //-------------------------------------------------
    //Check to see if delete button is pressed
    if(isset($_POST['formDelete']))
    {
        if(isset($_POST['ID']) && !empty($_POST['ID']))
        {
            $deleteID = $_POST['ID'];
            $result = mysql_query("DELETE FROM Project_Submissions WHERE ID ='".$deleteID."'");
        }
    }   
    //-------------------------------------------------
    if(isset($_POST['formCalledOne']))//Check to see if Call Attempt One button is pressed
    {
        if(isset($_POST['ID']) && !empty($_POST['ID']))
        {
            $callattemptoneID = $_POST['ID'];
            $callattemptonequery = mysql_query("UPDATE Project_Submissions SET CallAttemptOne=CURDATE() WHERE ID ='".$callattemptoneID."' AND CallAttemptOne IS NULL OR LENGTH(CallAttemptOne)=0");
        }
    }   
    //-------------------------------------------------
    if(isset($_POST['formCalledTwo']))//Check to see if Call Attempt Two button is pressed
    {
        if(isset($_POST['ID']) && !empty($_POST['ID']))
        {
            $callattempttwoID = $_POST['ID'];
            $callattempttwoquery = mysql_query("UPDATE Project_Submissions SET CallAttemptTwo=CURDATE() WHERE ID ='".$callattempttwoID."' AND CallAttemptTwo IS NULL OR LENGTH(CallAttemptTwo)=0");
        }
    }   
    //-------------------------------------------------
    if(isset($_POST['formCalledThree']))//Check to see if Call Attempt Three button is pressed
    {
        if(isset($_POST['ID']) && !empty($_POST['ID']))
        {
            $callattemptthreeID = $_POST['ID'];
            $callattemptthreequery = mysql_query("UPDATE Project_Submissions SET CallAttemptThree=CURDATE() WHERE ID ='".$callattemptthreeID."' AND CallAttemptThree IS NULL OR LENGTH(CallAttemptThree)=0");
        }
    }   
    //-------------------------------------------------
    if(isset($_POST['formEmailAttempt']))//Check to see if Email Attempt button is pressed
    {
        if(isset($_POST['ID']) && !empty($_POST['ID']))
        {
            $emailattemptID = $_POST['ID'];
            $emailattemptquery = mysql_query("UPDATE Project_Submissions SET EmailAttempt=CURDATE() WHERE ID ='".$emailattemptID."' AND EmailAttempt IS NULL OR LENGTH(EmailAttempt)=0");
        }
    }   
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please do not use the `mysql_` function as [they are deprecated](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). And your SQL is wide open to [SQL Injection](http://bobby-tables.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using parentheses in your queries:

```
UPDATE Project_Submissions SET EmailAttempt=CURDATE() WHERE ID ='".$emailattemptID."' AND (EmailAttempt IS NULL OR LENGTH(EmailAttempt)=0);
```

The reason for your query not working before is the order of precedence of the logical operators in the `WHERE` part. Logic is executed from left to right, so basically your query was the same as

```
SELECT WHERE (ID ='".$emailattemptID."' AND EmailAttempt IS NULL) OR LENGTH(EmailAttempt)=0;
```

thus every row where `LENGTH(EmailAttempt)=0` was true was included in the result. Besides enclosing the `OR` part in parentheses, you could also have reversed the order:

```
SELECT WHERE EmailAttempt IS NULL OR LENGTH(EmailAttempt)=0 AND ID ='".$emailattemptID."';
```

But besides that, as was mentioned in the comments before, you should never use variables directly in queries, since that leaves your code wide open to SQL injection attacks.

Comment: @new2programming I added a bit more verbose explanation to my answer. Hope it helps!